# Most Efficient way to calculate integrals/derivatives of inputted functions in Java?

Tags: java, derivative, integral

I now have an idea, that I use the function as a string, and I calculate the real integral by hand, and ask a question to the user what the definite integral is, but that isn't a real solution.

I was wondering if there was a way to input a function and output an integral/derivative (depending on user choice). My initial step was to put it into an array somehow, but given the many types of functions, this wasn't happening.

I researched everywhere, and I haven't found a method that actually does this with no additional code, nor any code that actually does this, period.

Also, I want to see if there was a way to make a GUI interface and plot inputted functions on to that, if that's possible too.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is known as *symbolic integration*. There's currently no fully general way to implement it, but there are some techniques available. One such is the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Alternatively, an easier problem than symbolic integration is [symbolic *differentiation* -- and, if the differential of the user's input is equivalent* to the expression which they were asked to integrate, then their integral is probably correct.

You may also want to consider using an existing CAS**, such as Mathematica, to implement this. They've already implemented most of the tools you're after.

*: Keep in mind, though, that two mathematical expressions may be equivalent without being identical, either in trivial ways (e.g, terms in a different order), more complex ones (e.g, large expressions factored differently), or fundamentally (e.g, trig functions replaced with complex exponentials or vice versa).

**: Computer algebra system

Comment: I believe Matlab has a Java API actually, not sure if it can solve this type of problem as I am not a user, but it was very popular in the Math department when I was in the University.

Answer (score 0):

[Javacalculus](http://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/) is what you are looking for.

Good luck!